# Node cannot be found in the current page after ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

After the table is reloaded inside div when I check on my console log and tried to check my node. it returns Node cannot be found.

For example, 
I did
`const test = d3.selectAll(...)`
, in my logs, I could select the tags that were present . right after I did a

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
   console.log(d3.selectAll(....))
});
```

my tags appear in my logs but as soon I tried to select my node I am receiving this warning which is making it impossible to do the modification. Any advice?

Comment: What is `d3`? Your [`ajaxComplete`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) function is going to be passed an argument that represents the return value from the AJAX call (the xhr), that is the object to look at for your data.

Comment: d3.js , once ajax is completed, i am suppose to to customised my frontend but its stating that node cannot be found

Comment: See the `ajaxComplete` documentation, you need your function to accept the 3 arguments that will be passed to it. Then you use the XHR to access the data.

Comment: Where you initialized your D3 ?